# In PHP str_contains returns 1 and no true

Tags: php

According to [the doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php), str_contains() should returns true or false.

Any idea why this piece of code returns `1` and not `true` ?
https://3v4l.org/B8nRL

```
echo str_contains('adm-users', 'adm-');
```

Thanks.

Comment: `echo true;` could have helped. Or perhaps `echo (str_contains('adm-users', 'adm-') === true);`. That's btw. why a [mcve] is required.